# Where to find open data for 3D vector fields?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, time-series

Three-dimensional vector fields are employed in fluid mechanics, climate modeling, magnetism, and other fields. Where can I find open data on real measurements of 3D vector fields, ideally across time?

Comment: Have you had a chance to google ? I bet there are some free or paid ones you want to explore them ?

Comment: Sure, I tried googling but without success.